# MVC Populate from a database a dropDownList of items related to particular userId

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 with Visual Studio 2013 and C#...

I can't work out how to populate a selective list of items from the column 'flightDate' in the Flights table based on the userId in the Users table.

Currently this is how my setup looks..

**Booking Controller**

```
public ActionResult EditBooking()
{
    ViewBag.BookingList = new SelectList(db.Bookings.All(t => t.UserId == userId).ToString(), "BookingId", "FlightDate");
    return View();
}
```

**Edit Booking View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditBooking", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))
{
@model project.Models.Booking
<div class="editor-label">
<label>What is the date of your booking?</label>
</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BookingId, (SelectList)ViewBag.BookingList)
</div>
}
```

- Currently I know the userId is being passed correctly.
- I don't know if my SelectList is actually generating a list of
  booking table rows with the correct userId attached to it?? -- my
  code could be wrong!
- I also don't know if I'm creating a list in the View with the flightDate as the value and the bookingId as the id for the list.

does someone know how to generate this list of conditional results from these tables of data?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you give it a shot it's working right or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code looks fine except `ToString()` after `Where()` which should be `ToList()`:

```
db.Bookings.Where(t=> t.UserId == userId).ToList()
```

Comment: the compliler says " 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' " and thinks i'm missing a reference or directive!?

Comment: Okay, I managed to get it to work with `db.Bookings.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).ToList()` Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! There's still a slight problem with the date in the dropdown also having a time included (even though the database field is formatted as just date)!! you know how to fix it?

Comment: You have to project again